# Align item .trailing without stretching container in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, spacing

I have a button which is nested in some other components. I want the button to be aligned to the right (trailing), even though the rest of the VStack items are leading.

When I use a Spacer() in an HStack, it stretches the HStack, and its parent container, to the width of the screen. I do not want to change the width of the parent, I just want to right align the button within the existing sized container.

Replicated below:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Long text to stretch container a bit")
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                Text("But not stretch too much")
                    .font(.caption2)
                    .opacity(0.8)
                HStack() {
//                       Spacer()
                    Button(action: {print("Hello")}) {
                        Text( "\(Image(systemName: "chevron.right"))")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.accentColor)
        .cornerRadius(15)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, `Spacer()` takes as much space as it can, growing your container. You can prevent this by adding `.fixedSize()` to the `VStack`, which means it will be fixed at its "ideal" size, instead of the "maximum" size that the spacer is aiming for:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Long text to stretch container a bit")
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                Text("But not stretch too much")
                    .font(.caption2)
                    .opacity(0.8)
                HStack() {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {print("Hello")}) {
                        Text( "\(Image(systemName: "chevron.right"))")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.accentColor)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .fixedSize()
    }
}
```